# Converting a WAV file to a spectrogram

Tags: c#, naudio, spectrogram

Hi im very new to this thing so please bear with me. I am trying to convert a WAV file to a spectrogram but arent sure how to begin with. I read on something that says to read the PCM data(which i think is my WAV file) and store it in an array in the WavReader class before  apply the FFT on it and converting it to GUI. Im currently using Naudio to achieve this but could not find anything that shows how to convert the WAV file to a spectrogram. Thanks

**Edit :**
I found out about converting PCM to FFT with Naudio and im stuck.

```
     using (var reader = new AudioFileReader("test1.wav"))
        {
          // test1.wav is my file to process
          // test0.wav is my temp file

            IWaveProvider stream16 = new WaveFloatTo16Provider(reader);
            using (WaveFileWriter converted = new WaveFileWriter("test0.wav", stream16.WaveFormat))
            {
                // buffer length needs to be a power of 2 for FFT to work nicely
                // however, make the buffer too long and pitches aren't detected fast enough
                // successful buffer sizes: 8192, 4096, 2048, 1024
                // (some pitch detection algorithms need at least 2048)
                byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
                int bytesRead;
                do
                {
                    bytesRead = stream16.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                    converted.WriteData(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                } while (bytesRead != 0 && converted.Length < reader.Length);
            }
        }
```

**Edit :** I would also like to know if it is possible to compare 2 spectrograms of 2 different files programmatically.

Comment: I think that the unity game engine offer a class of audio anylisys but i'm not sure.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could also use [BASS.NET](http://www.un4seen.com/bass.html#apis) library which natively provides all these features and is free.

The [Visuals.CreateSpectrum3DVoicePrint Method](http://www.bass.radio42.com/help/html/4f7e21aa-2c6d-bc83-56ef-bf171d6a6946.htm) does exactly that.

Feel free to ask for assistance if you're having a hard time using it.

**EDIT** : here's a quick and dirty sample

[image]

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private int _handle;
    private int _pos;
    private BASSTimer _timer;
    private Visuals _visuals;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bool spectrum3DVoicePrint = _visuals.CreateSpectrum3DVoicePrint(_handle, pictureBox1.CreateGraphics(),
                                                                        pictureBox1.Bounds, Color.Cyan, Color.Green,
                                                                        _pos, false, true);
        _pos++;
        if (_pos >= pictureBox1.Width)
        {
            _pos = 0;
        }
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string file = "..\\..\\mysong.mp3";
        if (Bass.BASS_Init(-1, 44100, BASSInit.BASS_DEVICE_DEFAULT, Handle))
        {
            _handle = Bass.BASS_StreamCreateFile(file, 0, 0, BASSFlag.BASS_DEFAULT);

            if (Bass.BASS_ChannelPlay(_handle, false))
            {
                _visuals = new Visuals();
                _timer = new BASSTimer((int) (1.0d/10*1000));
                _timer.Tick += timer_Tick;
                _timer.Start();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT 2**

You can provide a file name but you can also provide your own audio data using the other overload that accepts an IntPtr or use Bass.BASS_StreamCreatePush with Bass.BASS_StreamPutData.

Regarding comparing spectrograms you could do the following :

- Resize the image to a smaller size, reduce information by dithering it to 8-bit (with a good algorithm however)
- Compare the two images

However for comparing audio data I'd strongly suggest you to use fingerprints, it roughly does that but is much more robust than my suggestion.

Here's a fingerprinting library that is free to use :

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/206507/Duplicates-detector-via-audio-fingerprinting

Not entirely sure it would work for small samples, though.

**EDIT 3**

I'm afraid I can't find the link where I've read that but that's what they do: reducing data and comparing images such as the example below (last image):

(note : not to compare at all with image 1, it's something else but just to show why using a lower resolution might give better yields)

[image]

(from http://blog.echonest.com/post/545323349/the-echo-nest-musical-fingerprint-enmfp)

Now a very basic explanation of the process:

Comparison source A:

[image]

Comparison source B: (I've just changed a region of A)

[image]

Comparison result:

(done with Paint.Net by adding the former images as layers and setting 2nd layer blending to difference instead of normal)

[image]

If the fingerprints were to be identical the resulting image would be completely black.

And by reducing data to a 8-bit image you are easing the comparison process but keep in mind you will need a good dithering algorithm.

This is one is quite good :

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/66341/A-Simple-Yet-Quite-Powerful-Palette-Quantizer-in-C

Well it's not on par with Photoshop or Hypersnap's one (which IMO is exceptional) but that might be enough for the task.

And avoid at all costs [Floyd–Steinberg dithering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd%E2%80%93Steinberg_dithering) or something that does error diffusion.

Here some attempts on creating dithering algorithms : http://bisqwit.iki.fi/story/howto/dither/jy/

Take this with caution as I'm not an expert in the field but that's roughly how it's done.

Go to https://dsp.stackexchange.com/ and ask a few questions there, you might get useful hints on achieving this.

Comment: Just to clarify, for the code above do I just need to specify my filename for it to show the spectrogram?

Comment: Thanks a lot for ur answer. Really appreciate ur input on this. Regarding the audio fingerprinting that u provided, i tried to implement it before but somehow it only recognizes duplication of 2 similar music files but not of 2 audio files which has my voice. I would try to implement ur method of comparing spectrograms and hope for the best for it to work.

Comment: Alright, do not forget to mark answers as 'answer' or 'helpful' so other people can benefit from your question and eventual answers when searching for a similar issue. Also, you can ask questions at http://dsp.stackexchange.com/ regarding audio processing, you might get more attention on these subjects from users there.

Comment: Just one more thing. When u say resize the image to a smaller size and compare the two images, do u really mean comparing the physical picture of the spectrogram or is it another thing all together? How can it be implemented? Thanks again

Comment: The "image-like" comparison is not acoustically meaningful. You should first match up the time axis (linear shift) and frequency axis (scale factor, or linear shift on log-frequency axis). After that, a good similarity measure would be the remaining energy difference (sum of absolute differences)

Comment: I entirely agree with you, obviously one would use better metrics for the sake of quality :D